# How to customize grids in Map Composition in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

Please somebody help me out with Map Composition. In map composer how to put in geographical grid (not UTM grid)? And how to put only frame with ticks and annotation (not entire grid across a map)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, it is only possible to add a grid in the same coordinates used as project CRS. So if your project uses UTM, it will only add a UTM grid. It's possible to add an extra grid layer from e.g. Shapefile though.

Change the "grid type" to "cross" to avoid the entire grid being drawn. You can set the cross size really small or even to zero.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I thought so about UTM project. I will put extra grid layer. The grid type as cross works, only there are still no ticks. But it can be in use. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative to getting a cleaner map layout is that you can select the 'Frame and Annotations only' under Grid Type and change to Frame Style to 'Interior or/and Exterior Ticks).